# El kiu vorto venas la vorto "spegulo"?

Tags: etymology

Ĉu ĝi venas el la Germana vorto "spiegel"? La vorto estas eta konfuzanta al mi pro la finaĵo "-ulo". Komence, ĝi iĝas al mi pensi de la sufikso "-ulo".

Answer (score 1):

Laŭ [Etimologia Vortaro de Esperanto](http://reto.cn/php/esperanto/etimologia-vortaro-de-esperanto/):

> spegulo = Yid. shpigl, Ger. Spiegel, Lat. speculum

PIV montras la vorton ĉi tiel: ***spegul/o**

La steleto (*) signifas, ke ĝi estas Fundamenta vorto (do, trovebla en la zamenhofa [Universala Vortaro](http://www.akademio-de-esperanto.org/fundamento/universala_vortaro.html) de [Fundamento de Esperanto](http://www.akademio-de-esperanto.org/fundamento/index.html)), kaj la radiko *spegul* montras, ke ĝi estas neanalizebla vorto, t.e., ke ne eblas disigi  ĝin kiel kunmetaĵo de *speg-* kaj *-ul*.

Answer (score 0):

En PMEG oni nomas tiajn radikojn *ŝajnaj kunmetaĵoj* kaj ili meritas [tutan propran interesan paĝon](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/vortfarado/principoj/shajnkunmetajhoj.html).

En Esperanto vi havas radikojn kaj [afiksojn](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/vortfarado/afiksoj/index.html). Ĉiu el ili estas unuo, ne disigebla aŭ reduktebla (krom en karesaj formoj).

Kelkaj radikoj enhavas en si afiksojn, kaj tio povas esti konfuza, sed tio ne igas ilin kunmetaĵo.

Ekzemple:

```
katar-o estas malsano, ne aro da katoj (kat-ar-o)
vesper-o estas tagoparto, ne ero de vespo (vesp-er-o)
maŝin-o estas meĥanikaĵo, ne ina maŝo (maŝ-in-o)
```

*Spegulo* povus esti *ulo spega* (se speg/ signifus ion) sed fakte, ĉar ĝi estas spegul-o vi ne devas klopodi analizi ĝin.

Comment: Ekz. `lisp-eg-ul-o`

Comment: mi scias ke ekzistas iom vortoj kiu enhavas en si afiksojn kiu ne estas fakte afiksoj. Ĝi nur kreigas dusencaĵo ke igas ĝi pli malfacila lerni.